# Unknown SQL Server Query holds back datawarehouse load

Tags: sql, sql-server

We experience some problems with our automated loading of data into our data warehouse. The loading is scheduled via SQL Server agent jobs but lately we noticed some weird queries that are holding back the further loading.

Example query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    sum(dbo.FAC_WITNESS_QUEUE_ACTUALS.aabandons)
FROM
    dbo.DIM_DIVISION 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.FAC_WITNESS_QUEUE_ACTUALS ON (dbo.FAC_WITNESS_QUEUE_ACTUALS.division_sk = dbo.DIM_DIVISION.division_sk)
```

Notice that there is no `WHERE` clause which means the query loads very long time (more than an hour). When we kill this process we find another query with the same structure but another column in the `SUM` field.

There are no indexes on the tables mentioned in the `FROM` (also no primary key). The process is started with user SSIS (which is used for starting the jobs but no job is running using this kind of queries).

Anyone any suggestions in which direction to look?

Thx in advance

Comment: Is it possible that this is a subquery but when looking in the processes this is another session_id? (Query I use to check: SELECT sqltext.TEXT,
req.session_id,
req.status,
req.command,
req.cpu_time,
req.total_elapsed_time,
req.total_elapsed_time / 60000
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests req
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS sqltext)

Comment: If you have more to add (and especially if it's code) you should *edit* your question, not add a comment under it (the edit link is at the bottom left). When adding code, make sure you highlight it and hit the `{}` button so that it's properly formatted and syntax highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

First I am not sure the key DISTINCT is really useful here :-)

When you do a SUM or a COUNT on a large table, SQL LOCKS for writing the entire table to make sure that it is not changed whilst it is calculating the output. By default, no insert or update can be performed during that time.

There are ways to improve the Query or make it faster but this would need some sort of a time stamp column with an index or you could just add an autoinc bigint field column so that you can only SUM the new rows every day and add it to the results from the day before <= that would be my favourite way of doing it!

You could also look at the various LOCKING options:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc546505.aspx
Perhaps one of them is OK for what you need?

Finally, the JOIN might be very big (meaning too big!) and you could perhaps break it down using a CURSOR or such dreadful thing and add a WAITFOR DELAY as you loop through the values to let SQL breath a bit... Or add memory to your box if that is possible?

Comment: Hi @MichaelMoreno, The problem is that we didn't write the query in any of the jobs nor the reports that contain data. This query just pops up every morning. Thanks for the link though I will have a look at this to optimize our DWH